# Bootstrap Accordion isn't working with -xs- column sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created an accordion on my local Bootstrap site. I've created three columns within the collapse a href with classes of col-md-5, col-md-3 and col-md-2. At this point, the link still clicks and the accordion is fully functional, it just looks bad in mobile. So, I add the classes col-xs-5, col-xs-3 and col-xs-2 to the previous classes and now whenever the new classes are styling the accordion, the link does not click. I've even tried removing the -md- classes, but I think it has something to do with the -xs- classes. Does anyone know if accordion doesn't suppord -xs- classes?

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="row">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5">Introduction to the Linux Academy</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 difficulty">Beginner</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 time">01:00:36</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                   <a href="course-sub.php">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Course Details!</button>
                   </a>
                </div>
            </a>
       </h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you are saying but I suspect it is because your `<a>` has no width or height due to the child elements being floated. Try putting `class='clearfix'` on your `<a>` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Yep, @joshhunt is correct. You need to clear the floats so that you can click the toggle

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. I've put up my comment as an answer so that you can mark this question an answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it is because your `<a>` has no width or height due to the child elements being floated. Try putting `class='clearfix'` on your `<a>` and see if that fixes it.